# Extract unique elements from a list returned by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have countries list scraped from [this](http://www.wotif.com/) website having values like

(Note: this is the output of `all_countries` after iterating its elements)

```
<a  data-flexible="" SELECT data-id="AU" href="http://www.wotif.com/AU">Australia</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="NZ" href="http://www.wotif.com/NZ">New Zealand</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="ID" href="http://www.wotif.com/ID">Indonesia</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="TH" href="http://www.wotif.com/TH">Thailand</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="SG" href="http://www.wotif.com/SG">Singapore</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="GB" href="http://www.wotif.com/GB">United Kingdom</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="TH" href="http://www.wotif.com/TH">Thailand</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="AU" href="http://www.wotif.com/AU">Australia</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="AR" href="http://www.wotif.com/AR">Argentina</a>
<a  data-flexible="" data-id="NZ" href="http://www.wotif.com/NZ">New Zealand</a>
```

What I want to do is that get the only unique countries

This is what I have tried.

```
all_countries = countries.select('div#country-box ul li a')

for index,value in enumerate(all_countries):
    print(value)
    all_countries[index] = value.text

all_countries = set(all_countries)
all_countries = list(all_countries)

for index,value in enumerate(all_countries):
    print(value)
```

Hmmm okay, I have now unique elements but it does not maintain Order of those countries as they appear on site in that MultiSelectList and I also need values of attributes `data-id` and `href` and also the text of `a` tag for later use in my script.

If I do

```
all_countries = countries.select('div#country-box ul li a')
all_countries = set(all_countries)

all_countries = list(all_countries)
```

Would it be a good approach?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: So I get Unique elements based on `data-id` value

Comment: @falsetru If i do `all_countries = list(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(all_countries))` then I will have Australia 2 times because its markup is different. that is why I want to get unique based on `data-id`  values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `set` to store already-seen `data-id`s.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def iter_uniq_link(all_countries):
    seen = set()
    for c in all_countries:
        data_id = c.get('data-id')
        if data_id not in seen:
            seen.add(data_id)
            yield c
```

Usage:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''
... <body>
...     <div id="country-box">
...         <ul>
...             <li>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" SELECT data-id="AU" href="http://www.wotif.com/AU">Australia</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="NZ" href="http://www.wotif.com/NZ">New Zealand</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="ID" href="http://www.wotif.com/ID">Indonesia</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="TH" href="http://www.wotif.com/TH">Thailand</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="SG" href="http://www.wotif.com/SG">Singapore</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="GB" href="http://www.wotif.com/GB">United Kingdom</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="TH" href="http://www.wotif.com/TH">Thailand</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="AU" href="http://www.wotif.com/AU">Australia</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="AR" href="http://www.wotif.com/AR">Argentina</a>
...                 <a  data-flexible="" data-id="NZ" href="http://www.wotif.com/NZ">New Zealand</a>
...             </li>
...         </ul>
...     </div>
... </body>
... ''')
>>> all_countries = soup.select('div#country-box ul li a')
>>> list(iter_uniq_link(all_countries))
[<a data-flexible="" data-id="AU" href="http://www.wotif.com/AU" select="">Australia</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="NZ" href="http://www.wotif.com/NZ">New Zealand</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="ID" href="http://www.wotif.com/ID">Indonesia</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="TH" href="http://www.wotif.com/TH">Thailand</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="SG" href="http://www.wotif.com/SG">Singapore</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="GB" href="http://www.wotif.com/GB">United Kingdom</a>,
 <a data-flexible="" data-id="AR" href="http://www.wotif.com/AR">Argentina</a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to maintain order and uniqueness is to use an OrderedDict.  Add each unique value of `data-id` into the OrderedDict as a key.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Adding keys into such a dictionary will preserve their order of insertion when you iterate through it (with `.keys()`, for example).